# Is Earth's Moon gaining or losing mass?

Tags: the-moon, mass, dust, meteorites

The Earth gains mass from dust/meteors (and a tiny, tiny bit to increasing temperatures/energy), but loses mass from hydrogen/helium escaping and nuclear reactions.  It's estimated to have a net loss of about 50,000 tons a year.

What about Earth's Moon?  How much mass does it gain or lose due to these or other processes?

I'd assume it gets much less from dust/meteors, but also loses very little to space.  Does anyone have hard numbers for this?

Links: [Brian Koberlein](https://briankoberlein.com/blog/is-earth-gaining-mass/) and [Gizmodo](https://gizmodo.com/did-you-know-that-earth-is-getting-lighter-every-day-5882517)

Comment: "The Earth gains mass from increasing temperatures" Are you really shure? The effect of increasing mass by increasing energy by increasing temperature of a piece of iron is too small to be weighted.

Comment: that's referring to the increase due to an increase of energy, i'll clarify with an edit.

Comment: But the mass gain from temperature  (energy) is too small to be weighted.

Comment: yep, it's almost nothing, but i think it's still super interesting.  this answer has a lot of the earth stats https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/16725

Comment: I don't think the Moon loses much mass, all that can outgas already has and all the ice that can melt away has too